# How does a SvelteKit load function access local storage, when it runs on server side?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When visiting a deep link in my app, the component related to the deep link is the first page to be rendered, so I think its [SvelteKit load function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) must run **on server side**, is that correct?

If yes, I wonder how does the load function access local storage? It needs data from local storage like user credentials, tokens and so on.

I tried, but it seems that it has access to load function **only when** it runs on **client side**, not on server side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It needs data from local storage like user credentials, tokens and so on.

No, it does not. `localStorage` is a browser thing and you generally should *not* store anything security related in there (unless it is encrypted). If somehow a malicious script gets run, it would be able to access that information.

Authentication tokens should be stored in [HTTP-only cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

[The docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) note:

> The argument to a `load` function is a `LoadEvent` (or, for server-only load functions, a `ServerLoadEvent` which inherits `clientAddress`, `cookies`, `locals`, `platform` and `request` from `RequestEvent`)

So as you can see, in the server load function you would get access to the cookies.

Comment: So, the `load` function doesn't have access to local storage, but have access to `cookies`, is that correct? Sorry but I still don't understand how to access local storage. Could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: On the server it has access to cookies (`+page.server.js/ts`), if you define it in `+page.js/ts` it will run both on the client and on the server and it will not have access to cookies on the client. When it runs on the client you could access `localStorage`, but you should then make sure to not do so on the server. There probably is little point in doing so, though, because then the function behaves inconsistently.

Comment: To summerize it, as long as the `load` function runs on the server side, which is the case when visiting via a deep link, it does not have access to either cookies or local storage. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: You can simply ensure that it only runs on the server by defining it in `+page.server.js/ts`, that way it does not matter from where the page is accessed. And as stated, cookies can only be accessed on the server, local storage can only be accessed on the client.

Comment: Using HTTP-only cookies means you have to worry about CSRF attacks which you don't have to worry about if you store your tokens in localstorage. So it's a question of would you rather worry third party scripts stealing tokens or would you rather worry about protecting all of your endpoints against CSRF attacks. I wouldn't so adamantly say that storing tokens in localstorage is bad.

Comment: @hostingutilities.com CSRF is not that much of an issue any more. Most browsers will not just send credentials like they used to when the request comes from a different domain. (See [`SameSite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite), which should have reasonable defaults and can be set to be sure.)